# GPT2Model and GPT2Model with LM Head had different attention weight dimensions

Tags: huggingface-transformers

```
>>> from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2Model
>>> model = GPT2Model.from_pretrained("gpt2",output_attentions=True)
>>> tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
>>> text = "a,b,c"
>>> inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(text,return_tensors='pt',add_special_tokens=True)
>>> input_ids = inputs['input_ids']
>>> attention = model(input_ids)[-1]
>>> attention[0].shape
torch.Size([1, 12, 5, 5])
>>> import transformers
>>> m2 = transformers.AutoModelWithLMHead.from_pretrained("gpt2")
>>> at2 = m2(input_ids)[-1]
>>> at2[0].shape
torch.Size([2, 1, 12, 5, 64])
```

For your reference, `attention` is a tuple and `attention[0]` is for its first layer.

I can map everything except for `2` in `torch.Size([2, 1, 12, 5, 64])` vs `torch.Size([1, 12, 5, 5])`. What does that `2` mean?

I get these definitions from `bertviz` github repo:

```
            attention: list of ``torch.FloatTensor``(one for each layer) of shape
                ``(batch_size(must be 1), num_heads, sequence_length, sequence_length)``
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> m3 = m2.from_pretrained("gpt2",output_attentions=True)
>>> m3(inputs)[-1][0].shape
torch.Size([1, 12, 5, 5])
```

Strange that `transformers.AutoModelWithLMHead.from_pretrained` does not allow `output_attentions` to be one of its `args`.

Also edit config at run time does not work (`m2.config.output_attentions = True` won't work.)

Comment: If you feel that this is behavior that should be implemented, make sure to open a corresponding bug report on the Huggingface transformers [issue tracker](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues) and ideally link it to here (or vice versa).